# Aliasing memory addresses in GDB

Tags: gdb

I am looking for a way (directly or best approximation/alternative) to assign aliases to memory addresses in GDB, which would then show up with every function that prints this address (such as `x`, `find`, `info proc map` and so on).
Ideally, I'd also be able to set some sort of a range, which would then be used together with alias, to output offsets rather than direct addresses.

For example, using imaginary commands `alias` and `set-offset-range`

```
(gdb) info proc mem

      0x55c10c43e000     0x55c10c44f000    0x11000        0x0 /usr/bin/htop
      0x55c10c44f000     0x55c10c47d000    0x2e000    0x11000 /usr/bin/htop
      0x55c10c47d000     0x55c10c48c000     0xf000    0x3f000 /usr/bin/htop
      0x55c10c48d000     0x55c10c492000     0x5000    0x4e000 /usr/bin/htop
      0x55c10c492000     0x55c10c493000     0x1000    0x53000 /usr/bin/htop
      0x55c10c493000     0x55c10c495000     0x2000        0x0 
      0x55c10dee7000     0x55c10e185000   0x29e000        0x0 [heap]
...

(gdb) alias 0x55c10dee7000 'heap'       <-------------------
(gdb) set-offset-range $heap 0x29e00    <-------------------
(gdb) info proc map

      0x55c10c43e000     0x55c10c44f000    0x11000        0x0 /usr/bin/htop
      0x55c10c44f000     0x55c10c47d000    0x2e000    0x11000 /usr/bin/htop
      0x55c10c47d000     0x55c10c48c000     0xf000    0x3f000 /usr/bin/htop
      0x55c10c48d000     0x55c10c492000     0x5000    0x4e000 /usr/bin/htop
      0x55c10c492000     0x55c10c493000     0x1000    0x53000 /usr/bin/htop
      0x55c10c493000     0x55c10c495000     0x2000        0x0 
               $heap     ($heap+0x29e000)   0x29e000      0x0 [heap]

(gdb) x/32xb $heap
$heap:      0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
$heap+8:    0x91    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

Bonus question: if I need similar output tweaks in the future - what section of GDB manual should I be looking at to learn more about it?

Answer (score 0):

After some looking around and consulting helpful people on `#gdb`, turns out this isn't possible - either with `gdb` or Python extension API.

A workaround is to use `ld` to generate an artifical object file and fill it with synthetic symbols using `--defsym` flag, then load that object file into gdb using `add-symbol-file`.

I won't accept the workaround as solution, so if anyone has a better idea - bring it forth please.